# Access configuration files from a dependency in workbench

Tags: laravel, package, workbench

I've been working with Laravel for some time. I'm now in the process to learn to write my code onto packages for reusability issues.

I'm working on a Laravel 4.2 project.

I have two packages, "Package A" and "Package B". Every package has its own config files. And "Package B" has "Package A" as a dependency.

The problem is when "Package A" tries to access its own config values always get "array(0) { }".

I've using "Package A" in others Laravel projects as a dependency and it works fine. However I've not used it as a dependency of another package.

Need I do something to access these configuration values as a dependency? Maybe in the "Package B" Service Provider?

Thanks a lot, I hope I've explained well the problem, english is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by adding the "Package A" Service Provider into Service Providers array in app.php config file.

Thanks!